# Unsure of this array

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to understand some code. There is a Array declared called "Choices" which is used in a in a function called SetChoices. Then this function is called later on, with this

```
 SetChoices "${@//\\//}"
```

I'm not clear on what this is doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: '$@' refers to all of a shell script's command-line arguments and the parameter expansion is replacing all backslashed with forward slashes... How do you use the SetChoices function? Are there backslashes involved?

Comment: @conor : there is no array of this name in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax `${var/pattern/string}` is pattern substitution on shell variable.

If we run following script:

```bash
x="ABCfooDEF"
echo "${x/foo/bar}"
```

The output will be `ABCbarDEF`.

`$@` - this means *all arguments*, so `${@//\\//}` means:
in `@` replace all `\` (in script is `\\`, because it's escaped backslash) with `/`.

Comment: "replace /\" this is not 100% correct. the first `/` in the pattern indicates that all occurrences of the pattern should be replaced by the replacement string

Comment: @Rafael Would this be correct then.   
    **echo ${MESSAGE//e/E}**
    DEvElop a passion for lEarning. If you do, you will nEvEr cEasE to grow.

Comment: @conor Yes. As @Rafael said, `//` means replace all. Sorry for not noticing it previously (too many slashes)